# Finding a basis for a vector space with equations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3,x_4)\in R^4: x_1-2x_2+x_4 = 0, 2x_1-3x_2+x_3 = 0 \}$

I am trying to find a basis for V. Subtracting the constraints from each other yields $x_4= x_2/2+x_3/2$ this means that we have 3 degrees of freedom so the number of elements in our basis should be 3.

$(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,1/2), (0,0,1,1/2)$ are three linear independent vectors with span of V.

Then is this a basis for V? Am I allowed to subtract the constraint equations like so?

Thanks.

Comment: When you reduced two equations to one, you went from 2 degrees of freedom to 3.  You will find that NONE of your three vectors satisfy both original equations.

Comment: It is not. $V$ is defined by $2$ `linearly independent` equations, hence it has `codimension 2`. As it's a subspace of $\mathbf R^4$, this means it has dimension $4-2$.

Comment: What if th equation were not linearly independant?

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$u=(1,0,-2,-1)$$
$$v=(0, 1, 3, 2)$$

and you are done.

Every vector in V has a representation with these two vectors, 
as you can check with ease. And from the first two components of
u and v, you see, u and v are linear independet.

You have two equations in four unknowns, so rank is two.
You can't find more then two linear independent vectors.